# Turkey Visit Visa

Tags: visas, layovers, turkey

I am travelling From Canada to KSA Via Turkey- Do I need a visa to visit the city during my layover hours? 
If Yes- Should I apply for it online or Can I just get it at the airport?

Comment: I assume KSA is Kingdom of Saudi Arabia? What is your citizenship, what passport(s) do you hold? [These FAQs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa) seem to answer your question. You just need to find out if you would exit the transit lounge.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you are a Canadian citizen you will require an "e-visa" to enter Turkey. This can be applied for from the [Turkish e-visa site](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/), and generally only takes a few minutes to apply for and is normally issued immediately.

The cost of this visa depends on the country of citizenship, but for a Canadian is US$60.